# Is there a folder I can drop a .vsix file that will cause Visual Studio to update from that file the next time it opens?

Tags: visual-studio, updates, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I have developed an in-house VS Extension that I would like to make it easy to update for the user.  I've already worked out checking for new version and downloading the file.  I would like to have VS auto-update from the downloaded file on next startup.  Is that possible?  If so, how?

Comment: It's possible to make internal galleries of extensions: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/create-a-private-gallery-for-self-hosted-visual-studio-extensions/ Is there a reason you're not just doing that for your in-house uses? Then all the existing support of installing and updating works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a folder I can drop a .vsix file that will cause Visual
> Studio to update from that file the next time it opens?

I think you want to make a private vs extension gallery that contains the extensions only for your internal staff.

If so, you could just create such gallery by **Jason** said.

**1)** create a folder that only access to your internal staff or create a sharePoint site that is hosting the private gallery..

**2)** put all vsix files in that folder and then download [PrivateGalleryCreator.exe](https://github.com/madskristensen/PrivateGalleryCreator/releases). Put `PrivateGalleryCreator.exe` into the folder.

**After that**, click on the program to generate the `feed.xml` file.

**3)** enter **Tools**-->**Options**->**Environment**-->**Extensions and Updates**. Click **Add**, rename the new gallary and copy the full path of the `feed.xml` into **URL**.

Remember to click **Apply** to enable the URL.

[image]

**Based on it**, you can find the extensions on the new Gallery for all the internal staff.

Also, you can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/private-galleries?view=vs-2019).

**Besides**, if you want to auto-update these extensions, you should enable the **auto-update** options under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Environment`-->`Extensions and Updates`.